# Escaping Special Characters on cssSelector webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

how can I escape the following special character so i can use the ID on the div to get the form? This is my cssSelector:

```
#form > div:nth-child(4)>div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2)
```

And this is the html code:

```
div id="form:panelGridTransactionInfo" class="ui-panel ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You escape it with a backslash like so:

```
#form\:panelGridTransactionInfo > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2)
```

In Java, repeat the backslash to escape itself within the string:

```
"#form\\:panelGridTransactionInfo > div:nth-child(4) > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-of-type(2) > div:nth-of-type(2)"
```

Comment: Can you point me to some documentation why the `:` character needs to be escaped and in some other usecases e.g. `-` are automatically escaped?

Comment: @DebanjanB: There isn't a situation in which it's automatically escaped, unless you're referring to : appearing in strings, where it doesn't have any special meaning and is just a character. You escape it when it would otherwise be misconstrued as a pseudo-class delimiter, like all the :nth-child()s here.